# Error The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net

> I had this error when use upload file control  " **The given path's format
>   is not supported** " .

```
if (FUFile.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
            FUFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));

           ftier.Addpostfromfront(LoggedUserID, "4", txpost.Value, tempVar,  DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false, false);



        }
```

> when I checked the code I had :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? The error is apparent in the screen shot - you are mixing paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property FileName after extracting just the filename

```
    if (FUFile.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        string file = Path.GetFileName(FUFile.PostedFile.FileName);
        string tempVar = Path.Combine("~/res/Posts/", file);
        FUFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
       ftier.Addpostfromfront(LoggedUserID, "4", txpost.Value, tempVar,  DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false, false);
    }
```